# Listview Filter Returns filtered list but not the right data. Android

Tags: android, listview, filter

I managed to create a contact list picker purely based on what I learn on some tutorials. It works great. It can load up the contacts on my phone. I can select contacts (by checking the checkbox) and save it to database when I click the save button.
Whats missing is the filtering functions wherein I can filter the contacts with scrolling down the list. I did manage to make the filtering work, but it displays the wrong data.

Please take a look in this screenshot so you can't get confuse on what I'm trying to tell.

[image: four examples of the listview, filtered and unfiltered]

I can't post images yet. Sorry

Image 1 - 2 shows all the data in my listview.
In image 3, I tried to filter "y" the list should display "yuli" but instead it shows "Test1"
If you can see in the Logcat, There is "yuli" in there, so it only means that my filter works. To further test it out. I try "jam" the filter should return 2 jam's, but again it displays "Test1" and "jam" jam shows because it is the next on the list thats why he shows up. If you look at the logcat again, filter returns "jam" and "jamjam".

I checked all the code, If I come to think of it, it should work. I dont know where to look.

Please help me.

Here is the code too.

```
public class FragmentTab3 extends Fragment {

MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
Context context = getActivity();
Button myButton;
ListView listView;
EditText filterText = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab3, container,false);               
    new LongOperation().execute();
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    myButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
    filterText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    checkButtonClick();

}

//filter the items in the list
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("edit", "editting");
        if (dataAdapter != null) {
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        } else {
            Log.d("filter","no contact found");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Phonebook> {

    private ArrayList<Phonebook> phonebookList;
    private Filter filter;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,

    ArrayList<Phonebook> phonebookList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, phonebookList);
        this.phonebookList = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();
        this.phonebookList.addAll(phonebookList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name, number;
        CheckBox selected;
        ImageView imgView;
    }

//to inflate the view
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.blacklist_layout, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.number = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);
            holder.selected = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.imgView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.selected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Phonebook _state = (Phonebook) cb.getTag();
                    _state.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Phonebook state = phonebookList.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(state.getName());
        holder.number.setText(state.getNumber());
        holder.selected.setChecked(state.isChecked());
        Log.v("getImgUri", "" + state.getImgUri());
        holder.imgView.setImageURI(state.getImgUri());
        if (holder.imgView.getDrawable() == null) {
            holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        holder.selected.setTag(state);
        return convertView;
    }
    //here jam
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter(){
        if (filter == null) 
            filter = new AppFilter<Phonebook>(phonebookList);
            return filter;
    }
    /**class for filtering in arraylist listview, objects need a valid toString()method     */
    private class AppFilter<T> extends Filter{
        private ArrayList<T> sourceObjects;

        //contains the original data
        public AppFilter(List<T> phonebookList){
            sourceObjects = new ArrayList<T>();
            synchronized (this){
                sourceObjects.addAll(phonebookList);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence chars) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String filterSeq = chars.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if (filterSeq != null && filterSeq.length()>0){
                ArrayList<T> filter = new ArrayList<T>();

                    for (int i = 0, l = sourceObjects.size(); i < l; i++){
                        //the filtering itself:
                        Phonebook m = phonebookList.get(i);
                        if (m.getName().toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterSeq))
                            filter.add((T) m);
                    }
                    result.count = filter.size();
                    result.values = filter;
            } else {
                //add all objects
                synchronized (this) {
                    result.values = sourceObjects;
                    result.count = sourceObjects.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //this function is always called from the ui thread
            ArrayList<T> filtered = (ArrayList<T>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for (int i = 0, l = filtered.size(); i < l; i++)
                add((Phonebook) filtered.get(i));
            for (int i = 0; i <filtered.size(); i++) {
                Phonebook g = (Phonebook) filtered.get(i);
                Log.d("f", g.getName().toString());
            }
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Jam

Comment: if you use sqlite db why do you use an ArrayAdapter? why dont you use a SimpleCursorAdapter instead? when filtering you could use a FilterQueryProvider then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `publishResults()` you should assign `FilterResults results` to your adapters `private ArrayList<Phonebook> phonebookList;` to use the results.

But your adapter should 'carry' two ArrayLists. One the original and the other the filtered and 'in use' one.

I do not understand statement `add((Phonebook) filtered.get(i));`. To what would that be added?

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering. I'm just messing with the code I got on a sample and change a bit. Quick fix did that casting though.(The add((Phonebook thing). It did manage to fix the filtering when I replace the arraylist with the filtered result. But the list becomes blank after deleting the filter. I think this is the part where you are saying that I need add two Arraylist. Can you point it out how can I achieve that? Thanks again. I really new two this filtering part.

Comment: Repeat: `I do not understand statement add((Phonebook) filtered.get(i));. To what would that be added?`.

Comment: Sorryif that confuse you up.I test it out (add((phonebook)) and it added the filtered list into the phonebook arraylist. I remove it, and the filter still works fine, but it gives me the same output(the test1 thing), then I tried to put the filtered array list into my array adapter, the filtering works now it shows the right data, but the list don't go back to the full list when I erase the criteria of the filtering

Comment: Thats why you need two lists.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works perfectly! What I did is:     `clear();
dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
R.layout.blacklist_layout, filtered);
listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
notifyDataSetChanged();`  I don't know it this is the right right way of doing it. But it works. Thanks Again.